# ElasticSearch highlight showing wrong field

Tags: elasticsearch

If I insert this data in ElasticSearch:

```
PUT /a/b/1
{
   "content": "<a>Mussum<a> ipsum<a> cacilds<a>",
   "content_processed": "Mussum ipsum cacilds",
   "content.processed": "Mussum ipsum cacilds",
   "content.processed.x": "Mussum ipsum cacilds"
}
```

And perform the following query:

```
GET /a/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "cacilds"
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "pre_tags": [
         "<tag1><div class='h1'></div>",
         "<tag2>"
      ],
      "post_tags": [
         "</tag1>",
         "</tag2>"
      ],
      "fields": {
         "_all": {},
         "content": {},
         "content_processed": {},
         "content.processed": {},
         "content.processed.x": {}
      }
   }
}
```

The highlights I receive are:

```
        "highlight": {
           "content_processed": [
              "Mussum ipsum <tag1><div class='h1'></div>cacilds</tag1>"
           ],
           "content.processed": [
              "<a>Mussum<a> ipsum<a> <tag1><div class='h1'></div>cacilds</tag1><a>"
           ],
           "content": [
              "<a>Mussum<a> ipsum<a> <tag1><div class='h1'></div>cacilds</tag1><a>"
           ],
           "content.processed.x": [
              "<a>Mussum<a> ipsum<a> <tag1><div class='h1'></div>cacilds</tag1><a>"
           ]
        }
```

"content" and "content_processed" values is what I would expect. But "content.processed" and "content.processed.x" seems to be showing wrong data. I would expect them to have same result as "content_processed" but instead they have same result as "content". Why this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently field names should not include a dot.
There is an open issue with regard to supporting such fields : [issue #9059](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9059)  and [issue #7112](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7112)